# Is there a way to run Jenkins with Docker as non-root user?

Tags: docker, jenkins, yocto

I'm trying to build a yocto-image with Jenkins in Docker.
Running bitbake command as root-user causes many problems and I tried some workarounds like:

```
touch build/conf/sanity.conf
```

and setting this variable to be able to build as root user:

```
FORCE_UNSAFE_CONFIGURE=1
```

**My question is:** Is it possible to run Jenkins in a docker container with a non-root user?

**What I have tried:**

1. Setting USER jenkins in Dockerfile:

   ```
   # From official jenkins image.
   FROM jenkins/jenkins

   # Set root user
   USER root

   # Install recommended tools for yocto
   RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
       gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo gcc-multilib g++-multilib \
       build-essential chrpath socat cpio python python3 python3-pip python3- 
       pexpect \
       xz-utils debianutils iputils-ping python3-git python3-jinja2 libegl1- 
       mesa libsdl1.2-dev \
       pylint3 xterm file

   # Set working directory.
   WORKDIR /home/jenkins

   # Add user jenkins
   RUN adduser -D jenkins

   # change owner of /home/jenkins directory
   RUN chown -R jenkins /home/jenkins

   # Set user to jenkins
   USER jenkins

   # Update $PATH variable
   ENV PATH="${PATH}:/home/jenkins/bin"

   # Listening port at runtime.
   EXPOSE 8080
   ```

   After starting my container I looked into [system information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeQN9.png) of jenkins and saw that the user is still root.
2. Switching to user jenkins in Jenkinsfile with shell command

   ```
   pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
       stage('Test') {
           steps {
               dir('/home/jenkins/') {
                   sh """su jenkins
                         whoami"""
               }
           }
       }
   }
   }
   ```

   **Output:**

   ```
   + su jenkins
   + whoami
   root
   ```

I saw that this happens only in a docker container. I installed Jenkins on my local machine to test if there would be a difference and found out that Jenkins runs with user jenkins by default on my local machine.

Comment: The official docker images do not seem to run as root: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile
What container image are you using?

Comment: I am using this docker image from dockerhub: https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/

Comment: That looks like the same thing (although dockerhub really isn't trying very hard to show what Dockerfile might have been used), and clearly sets default user to "jenkins": https://hub.docker.com/layers/jenkins/jenkins/latest/images/sha256-20698f6f2ef0261534d7caaf08050547052cd9591ed0965b233610f97b352166?context=explore

Comment: Yes, I have read in other posts that docker itself is the problem (I'm not sure about this) because the processes are executed by root.

Comment: I will try to run the official jenkins image and check if there is a difference

Comment: What you said you are running seem to be the official ones. Also, I just tested and it definitely runs as user "jenkins"...

Comment: There seems to be no reason for you to do most of the things you do (create a user or directories or chown them or set workingdir): the upstream jenkins container already works so yours should too, just set user back to jenkins after you've done your apt-gets.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I went through the jenkins documentation and read this: NOTE: Avoid using a bind mount from a folder on the host machine into /var/jenkins_home, as this might result in file permission issues (the user used inside the container might not have rights to the folder on the host machine). If you really need to bind mount jenkins_home, ensure that the directory on the host is accessible by the jenkins user inside the container (jenkins user - uid 1000) or use -u some_other_user parameter with docker run.

Comment: One thing that I didn't wrote here is how i ran my container. I passed user root as argument because I wasn't able to run with default user jenkins. Probably because I bind mounted a volume and didn't made it accessible for user jenkins. And yes you are totally right. I didn' know that this user exists already so I added it to my Dockerfile